# PHP code execution time

Tags: php

How to find my code execution time?

I am using the below snippet.

I am not happy with that?

```
list ($msec, $sec) = explode(' ', microtime());
$microtime = (float)$msec + (float)$sec;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In LINUX:

#### For one simple code:

`time php -r "echo 'hello';"`

output:

hello
real    0m0.095s
user    0m0.033s
sys     0m0.055s

#### For a php file:

`time php hello.php`

output:

hello
real    0m0.073s
user    0m0.025s
sys     0m0.047s

Answer (score 21):

I have created this simple class for that:

```
class timer
{
    private $start_time = NULL;
    private $end_time = NULL;

    private function getmicrotime()
    {
      list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());
      return ((float)$usec + (float)$sec);
    }

    function start()
    {
      $this->start_time = $this->getmicrotime();
    }

    function stop()
    {
      $this->end_time = $this->getmicrotime();
    }

    function result()
    {
        if (is_null($this->start_time))
        {
            exit('Timer: start method not called !');
            return false;
        }
        else if (is_null($this->end_time))
        {
            exit('Timer: stop method not called !');
            return false;
        }

        return round(($this->end_time - $this->start_time), 4);
    }

    # an alias of result function
    function time()
    {
        $this->result();
    }

}
```

To time scripts, you can put it to use like:

```
$timer = new timer();

$timer->start();
// your code now
$timer->stop();

// show result now
echo $timer->result();
```

Answer (score 9):

I'm using following class to determine time elapsed:

```
class StopWatch {
    private static $total;

    public static function start() {
        self::$total = microtime(true);
    }

    public static function elapsed() {
        return microtime(true) - self::$total;
    }
}
```

You just have to call `StopWatch::start` at the beginning and `StopWatch::elapsed` whenever you want to know how much time elapsed from the start.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [parameter of microtime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) :

```
$microtime = microtime(true);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to profile your script, use XDebug + {K,Win}Cachegrind, these are free tools that provide a visual map of your code's execution.

Comment: +1 for suggesting a profiler instead of using microtime(), see http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler

Comment: There is useful function xdebug_time_index it is show elapsed time since start of the script

Answer (score 2):

If you want the actual processor timings:

```
$rUsage = getrusage();
echo 'User time = '.sprintf('%.4f',($rUsage['ru_utime.tv_sec'] * 1e6 + $rUsage['ru_utime.tv_usec']) / 1e6).' seconds';
echo 'system time = '.sprintf('%.4f',($rUsage['ru_stime.tv_sec'] * 1e6 + $rUsage['ru_stime.tv_usec']) / 1e6).' seconds';
```

Answer (score 0):

If running Unix, take a look at the [time command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_%28Unix%29):

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for sharing your information.

The below one also LITTLE BIT near of my solution.

```
function microtime_float() {
    list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());
    return ((float)$usec + (float)$sec);
}

$time_start = microtime_float();

SOURCE CODE

$time_end = microtime_float();
$time = round($time_end - $time_start, 4);

echo "Last uncached content render took $time seconds";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// Randomize sleeping time
usleep(mt_rand(100, 10000));

// As of PHP 5.4.0, REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT is available in the $_SERVER superglobal array.
// It contains the timestamp of the start of the request with microsecond precision.
$time = microtime(true) - $_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"];

echo "Did nothing in $time seconds\n";
?>
```