# execution time and memory uses by the code

Tags: php, memory-management, benchmarking, execution-time

I am a PHP coder. I don't find any way to get how many time is taken during execution of code.means execution time.
and How much memory space is used by the code during execution tim

I know the PHP INI setting but doesn't showed my solution.

How could i get that time and memory space unit with coding.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942385/php-code-execution-time

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tracking Memory Usage in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290611/tracking-memory-usage-in-php)

Answer (score 4):

I found this one in generator example.

```
$start_time=microtime(true);

//do something what you want to measure

$end_time=microtime(true);
echo "time: ", bcsub($end_time, $start_time, 4), "\n";
echo "memory (byte): ", memory_get_peak_usage(true), "\n";
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php#114136

Comment: this doesnt work unless you manually install a package called `php70w-bcmath`, where `70` stands for your PHP version

Comment: You can use round( $end_time - $start_time,4) instead of bcsub. round is part of Math what is core extension, it should work without any installation.

Answer (score 2):

I always use

```
microtime()
```

for timing, and

```
memory_get_usage()
```

for memory usage, together with my IDE (PHPStorm) and XDEBUG this gives quite some useful info.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php
and
http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
microtime()
```

at the begin of  your script, and at the end. The difference will be the execution time.
microtime return the timestamp with micro second wich is enough for your needs.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php